# HTML Canvas: How to color area under a line graph?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a mountain graph (line chart and area underneath is shaded) however, no matter what I try, the shaded area is not covering the whole area. Because my chart is an open path so fill results in area which is going through the chart line.

[image]

Below is a sample code that I put on W3School to show the problem.

I also saw some other questions on same lines, but following them too is resulting in same problem.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,150);
ctx.lineTo(100,70);
ctx.lineTo(150,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,140);
ctx.lineTo(250,90);
ctx.lineTo(300,110);
ctx.fillStyle ="red";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: You're just missing a single point at the bottom corner of your canvas. End with `ctx.lineTo(300,150);` before `ctx.fllStyle`.

Comment: Poorly asked question.

Comment: @PHPglue, I am sorry to say that your answer was poor and the above comment is not in good taste. Why ? Because you answered by modifying the requirement. I gave 5 lines and asked to fill area underneath. Why would you add another line from your side? That tells me that you are not aware of mountain graph. You could have asked for clarification before modifying my original requirement just to answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to `stroke()` your path first, then `lineTo(lastX, canvasHeight); lineTo(firstX, canvasHeight);` before calling `fill()`.

This way your filled area will always cover all the bottom area.
If you want to fill only to the max Y value, instead of to the bottom of the canvas, then you can grab this maxY from your points (commented part in below snippet):

```js
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

function plotPoints() {
  const pts = generatePoints(32);
  // first plot the stroke
  pts.forEach((pt) => ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y));
  ctx.stroke();
  // now define the bottom of the filled area
  const maxY = height; //Math.max.apply(null, pts.map(pt=>pt.y));
  // draw the missing parts
  ctx.lineTo(pts[pts.length - 1].x, maxY); // bottom-right
  ctx.lineTo(pts[0].x, maxY); // bottom-left

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"; // draw behind
  ctx.fill(); // will close the path for us
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // normal behavior

}
plotPoints();

function generatePoints(nbOfPoints) {
  const pts = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= nbOfPoints; i++) {
    pts.push({
      x: i * (width / nbOfPoints),
      y: Math.random() * height
    });
  }
  return pts;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Excellent that is what I was looking for.. Thank you.

Comment: Hi kaiido,  could you please modify your answer very slightly. I by mistake down voted you and now it won't let me change it unless the answer is edited. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. It was haunting me from 2018.

Comment: It would look a bit cleaner if `stroke` was done after `fill`. But I don't know if you can undo `lineTo`

Comment: Or you can do `lineTo` to the outside of the canvas so that the strokes on the sides are invisible

Comment: @janispritzkau or simply draw behind. I did it in an edit.

Answer (score -1):

It's like:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, E; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document, bod = doc.body;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var graph = E('graph'), ctx = graph.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(0,150); ctx.lineTo(100,70);
ctx.lineTo(150,100); ctx.lineTo(200,140); ctx.lineTo(250,90);
ctx.lineTo(300,110); ctx.lineTo(300,110); ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red'; ctx.fill(); ctx.stroke();
});
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:940px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#graph{
  width:300px; height:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Graph</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='main'>
      <canvas id='graph'></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out to me however, this solution will not help me. Your scenario worked just because your start and end point is at the end of the graph. In normal cases we will not have that. The graph will not original from (0,0) always and will not end at (width, height). Even If I try to have it there, it will look odd on graph and will indicate wrong price.

Comment: So the downvote is because of your lack of understanding basic Math. You should have been able to figure out where those x, y points were on your own.

Comment: Lol ... God bless you.. I am not capable of your great achievements. Wish you all success in life. Keep on answering and helping people.